# extracting plain-text from a binary file

Tags: python, file, binary

I have found a binary file which is really important for me.
If I open it in text editor, I see lots of binary data but some strings are in plain text.

I read my file in python by

```
with open(my_precious_file, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
```

fileContent contains lot of binary values `/x00` which do not have ascii corresponding characters, and my strings

How do I clean it up, i.e. return a string with only printable characters in ?

Comment: Why not treat the file properly, as the type it really is?

Comment: custom, undocumented, legacy, unknown file format

Comment: If it's undocumented, how do you know it's custom?

Comment: I wish I could tell you. that is the only piece of information I have

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the **[io module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/io.html#binary-i-o)**

EX:

```
import io
with io.open(filename,'rb',encoding='utf8') as f:
    fileContent = file.read()
```